# Magento - Can you show stock levels when a configurable product selection has been made

Tags: magento, product, stock, configurable, availability

When a variation has been selected I want it to then display how many of that selection is in stock. For example for a t-shirt i select colour red and size large it would then say 4 in stock in this variation.

I don't mind whether its editing code in default.phtml or adding an extension.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

First load the *product* and *stock* models respectively:

```
//Load product Model
/* Via SKU */
$sku = productSKU; //Pass the simple product SKU here
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
// Via ID: $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);

//Stock Model
$_stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product);
```

And then get the quantity from *stock* model using this:

```
$_productQTY = $_stock->getQty();
```

If you want to show the results instantly you could integrate some AJAX calls.